# Audio stopped working suddenly on Samsung Galaxy devices (Ionic Cordova Apps)

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I have several Ionic / Cordova apps that play local audio (HTML5 player).  They worked previously and suddenly stopped playing audio last week, around October 24th, 2016 for Samsung Galaxy devices.  Seems to be isolated to only Galaxy devices.

Does anyone know of any Android updates that would cause this functionality to break or how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the meta tag on index.html. Make sure the meta tag doesn't have `media-src *`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *  'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 'self'  data: cdvfile://* content://*;">
```

This should be removed.

Comment: I can verify this is the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Support for HTML5 is not really great in browsers/android.
Please use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media or try to create custom plugin and use native approach for playing audio.